# Dumping Java Heap File on OutOfMemoryError using Jmap

Tags: java, out-of-memory, heap-memory, heap-dump, jmap

I've been trying to dump the heap file when an OutOfMemoryError occurs on a given Java process using Jmap.

I have been able to dump the heap file but I want to add the HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError flag to Jmap but I think I'm doing something wrong. Am I doing something wrong? I've tried:

```
jmap -J-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -dump:live,file=/home/eduardo2/dumpfile.hprof 18763
```

When I run the above it just says the following -- but it doesn't wait for the OutOfMemoryError:

```
>> Dumping heap to /home/eduardo2/dump21file.hprof ...
>> Heap dump file created
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are mixing up two different things:

- Use `jmap` to capture a heap dump from a running process like you did. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jmap.html.
- Use `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` on *the java process you are expecting to throw the `OOM`*. If the exception occurs, a dump will be written to the current directory. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/tsg/TSG-VM/html/clopts.html#gbzrr